# AAD-Integrated Authentication with Azure Active Directory fails

Tags: azure, adfs

We have an ADFS setup completed on one of our Azure virtual machine, and we have one Sql managed Instance created in azure portal.
We have federated our domain and successfully connected with 'Sql managed Instance' via AAD-Integrated authentication from SSMS.
Our problem is that when we try to connect this Sql managed Instance from our IIS application with AAD-Integrated authentication method

```
(string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=XXXXXXXXX; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=testdb;")
```

, we get the following error on screen:

```
Message - > One or more errors occurred. Inner Exception -> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> AdalException: MSIS7069: The specified request failed. at ADALNativeWrapper.ADALGetAccessToken(String username, IntPtr password, String stsURL, String servicePrincipalName, ValueType correlationId, String clientId, Boolean* fWindowsIntegrated, Int64& fileTime) at System.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryNativeAuthenticationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.<>c__DisplayClass134_1.b__0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() ---> (Inner Exception #0) AdalException: MSIS7069: The specified request failed. at ADALNativeWrapper.ADALGetAccessToken(String username, IntPtr password, String stsURL, String servicePrincipalName, ValueType correlationId, String clientId, Boolean* fWindowsIntegrated, Int64& fileTime) at System.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryNativeAuthenticationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

*Also we checked into ADFS logged issues and got the following error logged as follows:*

```
Log Name: AD FS/Admin
Source: AD FS
Date: 7/29/2021 12:26:45 PM
Event ID: 111
Task Category: None
Level: Error
Keywords: AD FS
User: Domain\testuser
Computer: Name of our adfs server(Not mentioned the exact name due to sensitive data)
Description:
The Federation Service encountered an error while processing the WS-Trust request.
Request type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue
Additional Data
Exception details:
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.ADAccountValidationException: MSIS3173: Active Directory account validation failed. ---> Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityServer.ClaimsPolicy.Engine.AttributeStore.Ldap.AttributeStoreDSGetDCFailedException' was thrown.
```

Are we missing anything in the whole process?

**Edit1:**
I have one confusion regarding federated domain. The domain which we are using in our client machine, has to be primary domain in our Azure active directory OR can it be just in custom domain list in Azure active directory?

**Edit2:**
Finally, we were successful in connecting to our IIS application via AAD-Integrated authentication. We just changed our application pool's identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity(default option) to our domain user and voila, it worked like a charm. Hope somebody can get benefited from this.

Comment: Is the computer account setup as a user in ADFS?

Comment: Yes, the computer account is setup as a user in ADFS

Comment: Is the application running under the computer account in IIS? Or is it running under the default application pool? If the latter, you'll need to change the application pool settings so that the app runs under the computer account and not the application pool default identity. [IIS Application Pool Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#:~:text=Right%20click%20the%20application%20pool,ApplicationPoolIdentity%20from%20the%20combo%20box.)

Comment: IIS application is running with the user registered in ADFS. Also this user is synced with azure active directory.

Comment: Perhaps it's a firewall issue? Have you tried with a different AD account for the app pool  and see if that works? You can also check this MSDN document [troubleshoot-ad-fs-sso-issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/troubleshoot-ad-fs-sso-issue)

Comment: Currently we haven't configured any firewall settings at VM and DB end. I ll try to troubleshoot with your mentioned link and will update you the same

Comment: I tried troubleshooting with the above mentioned link, but still no luck.
Also i checked with firewall settings and found no such settings set for them.
Also tried with different user but still getting the error